# No error whatsoever, still not working

Tags: angularjs

I don't seem to get angularjs running.
Short description: All i'm trying to do here is to reach the orderservice thru the 3 steps. Route -> orderController -> orderService and there console.log() a message. This will later make a ajaxcall to server and retrive some data to play with.

Problem seem to occure when app.js is trying to call controller and nothing happens. No error, nada.

**View loading JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_AngularJs/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_AngularJs/controllers/orders/orderController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_AngularJs/service/orderService.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="app">


</div>
```

**app.js**

```
console.log("app.js LOADED...");

angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'app.controller', 'app.service'])
 .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/orderList.htm',
            controller: 'MyCtrl1'
        });
    }
]);
```

**orderController.js**

```
console.log("orderController.js LOADED...");

angular.module('app.controller', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'orderService', function ($scope, orderService) {
       console.log("hej");
       init();

       function init() {
          console.log("hej");
          var hej = orderService.query();
          console.log(hej);
       }

    }
]);
```

**orderService**

```
console.log("orderService.js LOADED...");

angular.module('app.service', [])
.service('orderService', [
    function() {
        return {
            query: function() {
                // the query code here.
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

**Structure**

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Your title and your description both leave a lot to be desired. Describe your application and what it's supposed to do, please.

Comment: do you mean controller is not working?

Comment: Update a short short description @isherwood.

Yeah, seems to stop at app.js, never calls ordercontroller.js init function to do a console.log()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have `ng-view` in your html in order to work with $routeProvider add following code to html is one way to do it...

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

but if you want to work your example which is working (I tested it here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/85Nj50yFHudXrni0zGkg?p=preview) look console output...) just add ng-controller to one of your html tag like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, tried to put it in div but thats hard-coded way and there must be a way to make this work without naming controllers in the view?